# Codeception do not quit upon error

Tags: testing, codeception

When running tests with Codeception (v2.1.6.) my tests (regardless of Functional or Acceptance) will always quit on the first failure.

I would like to generate a complete report but it seems impossible. Any ideas?

Comment: Are your failures fatal? Make sure that the aren't.

Comment: If I do $I->see('yada') and it's not there, does that mean its fatal? should I use canSee througout my whole application to make it non-fatal?

Comment: It stops that particular test, but other tests (not assertions) should be executed.

Comment: so what do you advice then? to use canSee throughout the application?

Comment: Maybe your tests should be smaller.

Comment: What I just want is the test to continue testing other stuff when something fails.

Comment: so when I do $I->see('My Title') and it fails, I still want it to check if $I->see('My description') is underneath the title.